# Can other programs then Windows Hello access an external IR Camera?

Tags: windows-10, webcam, spyware, windows-hello, ir

I got two web cameras, one normal and another which has an IR camera build in for my Windows Hello sign in function. I can access my normal camera in various applications but I just don't see any app or other way to open up a viewfinder for the IR Camera except when you set it in Windows Hello.

I have put tape over every web camera (except the IR one) but I'm uncertain if it even is possible to spy on me through that IR camera? Anyone who knows a way to spy on me through it? Or does Windows somehow lock it for 3rd party apps after being connected to the Windows Hello login method?

I want to be able to just login without having to take away and reinstall the tape every time i login. It kind of defeats the purpose of having this ease of use login method to begin with.

Here is an similar camera to the one that I got right now:
https://www.conrad.com/p/csl-computer-hello-dx1-hd-webcam-1280-x-720-pix-stand-clip-mount-supports-windows-hello-1696254

Comment: Yes; However, the camera must meet the requirements for Windows Hello, which are wel documented

Comment: I got a camera that works with Windows Hello. Do you mean that an app which wants to access the camera must "meet the requirements" ? I'm not sure what you are trying to answer?

Comment: Most Windows Hello devices are connected by USB.  Windows Hello doesn’t prevent the camera from being used.